# Is it possible to change a where clause dynamically in a trigger (Oracle)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, where-clause

Select ...something... from ...somewhere... where condition1 and (if updating then condition2 elsif deleting then condition3).
This is of course just pseudocode. Is it possible to make such a statement? When I try it underlines `updating`. What should I use? Case? Logical operators? all seem to be forbidden. This is just after begin in a trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FIX_UPD_LIMITS
BEFORE UPDATE OR DELETE ON LIMITS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    is_deleted_dependant VARCHAR2(1 BYTE);
    is_editable_dependant VARCHAR2(1 BYTE);
BEGIN
    SELECT IS_DELETE, IS_EDITABLE 
    INTO is_deleted_dependant, is_editable_dependant
    FROM MAP_CALCULATION MC 
        INNER JOIN map_calculation_group MG ON MC.ID_CALC = MG.ID_CALC
    WHERE MG.ID_CALC = MC.ID_CALC
    AND ((UPDATING AND mg.id_group = :new.id_group)
        OR (DELETING AND :old.id_group = mg.id_group)
    ); 

    IF UPDATING AND (is_editable_dependant = 'F' OR is_deleted_dependant = 'T') THEN
        ...   
    ELSIF DELETING AND (is_editable_dependant = 'F' OR is_deleted_dependant = 'T') THEN
        ...
    END IF;

END;
/
```

Comment: How does a "select" statement do updating?

Comment: Show us your trigger code attempt.

Comment: Edited, please look

Comment: Fully flexible dynamic sql within PL/SQL is accomplished with the package `dbms_sql`. The `execute immediate` command allows some flexibility with respect to placeholders but not as much flexibility as `dbms_sql`.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATING and DELETING are PL/SQL keywords and only valid in trigger bodies. The SQL engine doesn't understand them. Hence the compilation error.

:NEW.GROUP_ID will be populated when you're updating and null when you're deleting. So this should work for you:

```
    SELECT IS_DELETE, IS_EDITABLE 
    INTO is_deleted_dependant, is_editable_dependant
    FROM MAP_CALCULATION MC 
        INNER JOIN map_calculation_group MG ON MC.ID_CALC = MG.ID_CALC
    WHERE MG.ID_CALC = MC.ID_CALC
    AND mg.id_group = coalesce(:new.id_group, :old.id_group)
    );
```